# Determine max length allowed in a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

The structure of the table is like:

```
registrant_id   varchar(16)
registrant_name     varchar(128)
```

I want to run a query that displays all those entries which match the maximum PERMISSIBLE length, ie what I do currently do for the above:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tm_registrant`
WHERE length( `registrant_name` ) = 128
```

However, I dont want to hardcode 128 as I have many columns and want to run one query to see all the entries which have atleast one completely 'filled up' column.

Comment: @BoltClock - are you sure???? That sounds quite counterinuitive. And my mysql table seems to cut off input at that point...

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
   AND table_schema = 'your_db_name'
   AND column_name = 'your_column_name'
 LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination left, right and len to extract the lenght of the varchar fields using this command in your SQL statment: 
SHOW FIELDS FROM tablename1 Where Field = 'registrant_name'

Or you can look in the NFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html

Comment: can an automatic query be generated so I can see what all fields have been "filled" completely (which is a problem for me because mysql doesnt complain if the input size is larger than what the varchars can hold...)

Comment: I don't think of a direct way of verifying if a field is filled or not but if you try to update a field with a longer string then it can store you should get this warning back: Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'name'